# Updating a feature in GIT

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I currently have a feature branch in GIT. This branch was created from the develop branch.
Now certain things on the develop branch have changed and I want those changes to appear in the feature branch. I wanted to know how I can do that or what my options are

Comment: Do a fetch, and then merge `origin/develop` into your local feature branch. I don't use SourceTree much, so I don't recall exactly how to do it in that (and I'm on Linux, so I can't check right now). Also, if you mean [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview) (I'm assuming you do), then the tag is `atlassian-sourcetree`, not `source-tree`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the features from the develop branch by first updating both branches (the feature branch and the development branch), then checking out the feature branch and merging the development branch onto the feature branch.

```
git fetch origin develop
git fetch origin feature/new_gadget
git checkout feature/new_gadget
git merge --no-ff develop
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following diagram:

```
[master] *---*---*
                  \
[develop]          *---*---*---*---*
                            \
[feature]                    A---B---C
```

You have two main options:

1. **Merge** the changes from `develop` into `feature`:

   ```
   [master] *---*---*
                     \
   [develop]          *---*---*---*---*---.
                               \           \
   [feature]                    A---B---C---D
   ```

   Here, `D` is a new merge commit. `A`, `B` and `C` are identical to what they were beforehand.
2. **Rebase** your `feature` work on top of `develop`:

   ```
   [master] *---*---*
                     \
   [develop]          *---*---*---*---*
                                       \
   [feature]                            E---F---G
   ```

   Here there is no merge commit, but commits `E`, `F` and `G` will have different hashes from their matching `A`, `B` and `C` commits from before the reboase. This is only a good idea if you haven't shared your existing `A`, `B` and `C` commits with anybody.